# When should we call addDisposableTo(disposeBag) in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, rx-swift

We create a `DisposeBag`, and a `Observable`, subscribe the `Observable` and then `addDisposableTo(disposeBag)`, I know when the `DisposeBag` is going to deinit, it will call `dispose()` to release resources otherwise it will lead memory leak.

If the `Observable` send `Complete` or `Error` that terminate in finite time. When the `Observable` terminate before `DisposeBag` deinit, do I have the need to call `addDisposableTo(disposeBag)`? Does `DisposeBag` automatically release the observer that subscribed to it when it received terminated message?

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

Observable.just("")
    .subscribe { event in
        print(event)
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Should I have to `.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)` explicitly? I think after sending "", the `Observable` will terminate and releasing the observer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are certain that the observable completes in a *deterministic way* - like using `just` in your example, or using `take`, `takeUntil`, etc. -, you may choose to not use the DisposeBag.

You might get a compiler warning, that actually explains this behavior well and how to work around it. But in general, it is more future-proof if you use DisposeBag anyway.

See: [Unused disposable warning](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Warnings.md#unused-disposable)

Answer (score 0):

Dispose bags are used to return ARC like behavior to RX. When a DisposeBag is deallocated, it will call dispose on each of the added disposables.

It is used to dispose of old references that you pass in the closure and resources that are not needed anymore(and which were apparently not used): for example an open HTTP connection, a database connection or a cache.

So if we have any resources that can be left, you should call it.

More in [this article](http://swiftpearls.com/RxSwift-for-dummies-1-Observables.html).