# Subscribe to last value after completed on RxSwift PublishSubject

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I'm looking for something like this:

```
let observable = PublishSubject<String>()
observable.onNext("1")
observable.onCompleted()

_ = observable.subscribeNext { s in
    print(s)
}
```

So I want to subscribe to the Observable after it has already been completed and still get the values (or just the last value).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're using the wrong `Subject` to get what you want. [Take a look at the descriptions of the Subjects](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/72122e3e435b35a1d72f256a5b6e3929cbd223f1/Rx.playground/Pages/Working_with_Subjects.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift#L33):

**PublishSubject**: Broadcasts new events to all observers as of their time of the subscription.

**ReplaySubject**: Broadcasts new events to all subscribers, and the specified bufferSize number of previous events to new subscribers.

**BehaviorSubject**: Broadcasts new events to all subscribers, and the most recent (or initial) value to new subscribers.

**Variable**: Wraps a BehaviorSubject, so it will emit the most recent (or initial) value to new subscribers. And Variable also maintains current value state. Variable will never emit an Error event. However, it will automatically emit a Completed event and terminate on deinit.

---

So, don't use `PublishSubject`, since it only broadcasts *new events* upon subscription.

You can use `ReplaySubject` to get all previous events, or you can use `ReplaySubject`, `BehaviorSubject`, or `Variable` to get the most recent value.

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

// ALL previous events
let subject = ReplaySubject<String>.createUnbounded()
// or use this to get just the last, say, 4:
//   let subject = ReplaySubject<String>.create(bufferSize: 4)
// or use one of these to get the most recent:
//   let subject = ReplaySubject<String>.create(bufferSize: 1)
//   let subject = BehaviorSubject(value: "blah")
//   let subject = Variable("blah")

subject.onNext("blah")
subject.onNext("foo")
subject.onCompleted()

subject
    .asObservable()
    .subscribeNext { print($0) }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Outputs:

> blah
>   foo

Comment: Thank you. Quick question, if I do `_ = subject ...` I don't need `addDisposableTo(disposeBag)` correct?

Comment: That would get rid of the compilation warning, but you should be sure you know what you're doing first.  This answer explains it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37725469/343299